# How to convert `long` to `ValueWrapper` with NebulaGraph?

Tags: nebula-graph

I get a Relationship after a query with the Nebula Graph Java client, and then the properties of the relationship are written to map, shown as below:

```
Map<String, ValueWrapper> props = ((Relationship) value).properties()
```

Then I want to add `src_vid`, `dst_vid`, and `rank`, shown as below:

```
props.put(“srcVid”, ((Relationship) cvtedValue).srcId());
props.put(“dstVid”, ((Relationship) cvtedValue).dstId());
props.put(“rank”, ((Relationship) cvtedValue).ranking());
```

But the last rank cannot be added to the map because it's a long value.

Is there a way to convert it to value wrapper?

Comment: Related: *[Is moderator intervention required for these Nebula Graph questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426494/is-moderator-intervention-required-for-these-nebula-graph-questions)*

Answer (score 0):

Try Long → Value → ValueWrapper

new ValueWrapper(new Value(Value.IVAL, 10L), “utf-8”, 28800))